# LearnR Rmd knit to pdf failed to compile after update of MikTex

Tags: r, command, latex, learnr

After I updated MikTex to the latest version, my Rmd files don't compile anymore. I installed tinytex, reinstalled miktex, R and RStudio several times. I use some newcommands like \C, \G etc. in a tex document which I include in my Rmd file. I use windows 10, the latest versions of R, RStudio and Miktex.

I asked a colleague (who had no compiling issues) to update his MikTex as well. After updating his MikTex, he had the same issue.

**Here is the Rmd code:**

```
---
documentclass: scrartcl
fontsize: 11pt
output:
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: commands.tex

---

This is an example:

\begin{itemize}
    \item hello
    \item world
\end{itemize}
```

And here is the tex code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{amsmath}                    
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\usepackage{icomma}                     
\usepackage[right,official]{eurosym}    
\usepackage{hyperref}                   
\usepackage{booktabs}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}      
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Seitenformat und Layoutparameter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\hbadness=1000
\tolerance=10000
\voffset-2.80cm
\hoffset-2.60cm
\topmargin1.50cm
\headheight0.65cm
\headsep1.0cm
\topskip0cm
\textheight24.00cm
\footskip1.5cm
\footnotesep11pt
\evensidemargin2.50cm
\oddsidemargin2.50cm
\textwidth16cm
%\parindent0cm
%\parskip1.5ex plus0.5ex minus 0.5ex

% simple letters
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathbb A}}
\newcommand{\B}{{\mathbb B}}
\renewcommand{\C}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\mathbb D}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\mathbb E}}
```

And I get:

processing file: example1.Rmd
|......................................................................| 100%
ordinary text without R code

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS example1.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output example1.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\saski\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\saski\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --include-in-header commands.tex --variable graphics
output file: example1.knit.md

! LaTeX Error: Command \C undefined.

Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile example1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See example1.log for more info.
Ausführung angehalten

Comment: My guess is that one or more of the latex packages that are being loaded are not installed. Either install them manually or make sure that miktex/tinytex are set up so that they automatically install packages.

Comment: @Till The error would look different, something like `! LaTeX Error: File filename.sty not found.`

Comment: Thank you! It works when I delete the One-letter newcommands

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to avoid one letter macro names

---

your code no longer works because `\C` is now only defined by hyperref under certain circumstances, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582625/command-c-already-defined-and-the-hyperref-package/582630#582630 for more information

If you use `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand` you can see that the error vanishes

```
% simple letters
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathbb A}}
\newcommand{\B}{{\mathbb B}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\mathbb D}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\mathbb E}}
```

(but you should still not do that, use some other macro names instead if the one letter names)

---

Conclusion: don't use one letter macro names